# free() invalid pointer

Tags: c, pointers, free

I'm getting the familiar free(): invalid pointer error. In trying to debug, I ended up commenting out each free() in my code, one by one, *until there were none left* and I'm still getting this runtime error. Has anyone else run into a similar issue?

By the way - it's difficult for me to debug this using gdb, because the entire server doesn't actually crash when the error message is printed, just the particular forked process that was handling the single client.

Thank you.

```
==============================
*** glibc detected *** ./server: free(): invalid pointer: 0x08641a38 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6b961)[0xefe961]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6d28b)[0xf0028b]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6d)[0xf0341d]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x21)[0x4c74d1]
./server[0x804b499]
./server[0x804b2ad]
./server[0x804aecd]
./server[0x804ad36]
./server[0x804a3a3]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x2fa6f)[0xec2a6f]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x2facf)[0xec2acf]
./server[0x804966b]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7)[0xea9e37]
./server[0x8049331]
======= Memory map: ========
00338000-00352000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 394236     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
00352000-00353000 r--p 00019000 08:01 394236     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
00353000-00354000 rw-p 0001a000 08:01 394236     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
003c1000-003c2000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
0041d000-004fc000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 792946     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
004fc000-00500000 r--p 000de000 08:01 792946     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
00500000-00501000 rw-p 000e2000 08:01 792946     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
00501000-00508000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00664000-00688000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 394245     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
00688000-00689000 r--p 00023000 08:01 394245     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
00689000-0068a000 rw-p 00024000 08:01 394245     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
00793000-007af000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 394195     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
007af000-007b0000 r--p 0001b000 08:01 394195     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
007b0000-007b1000 rw-p 0001c000 08:01 394195     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
00960000-0096a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 394254     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
0096a000-0096b000 r--p 00009000 08:01 394254     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
0096b000-0096c000 rw-p 0000a000 08:01 394254     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
00e93000-00fed000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 394208     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
00fed000-00fee000 ---p 0015a000 08:01 394208     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
00fee000-00ff0000 r--p 0015a000 08:01 394208     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
00ff0000-00ff1000 rw-p 0015c000 08:01 394208     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
00ff1000-00ff4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
08048000-08056000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1084793    /home/mwrosen/cpe464/prog2/server
08056000-08057000 r--p 0000d000 08:01 1084793    /home/mwrosen/cpe464/prog2/server
08057000-08058000 rw-p 0000e000 08:01 1084793    /home/mwrosen/cpe464/prog2/server
08641000-08662000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7600000-b7621000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7621000-b7700000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7718000-b771b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7729000-b772c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
bfacf000-bfaf0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
```

Comment: Jim - the code is long, and it's a school assignment so I can't post my solution on the Internet. Mainly, I was hoping someone has some insight as to why this error is occurring even after all free()s have been removed from my code. Sorry!

Comment: @MitchellSalad: In the course of reducing your code to a repro case (<50LoC, self-contained, reproducing the problem) you are very likely to find the issue. If not, you have the perfect piece of code to bring here and ask for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to debug your issue.

If your error persist even with all `free` removed, it could be because some code is overflowing its memory zone (e.g. a buffer overflow).

Answer (score 7):

If your code trashes a pointer used by some other code, other code may wind up calling `free` on an invalid pointer. Likely you are accessing some memory you don't own.

There are many ways this can happen, here are two common ones:

1) If you declare an array like `int f[7];`, the last array element is `f[6]`. Modifying `f[7]` can corrupt someone else's memory.

2) If you save a pointer to an object allocated on the stack, that object goes out of scope, and then you modify something through that pointer, you can corrupt someone else's memory.